# Python - print values not being returned by function

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm learning about python at the moment and came across this code:

```
class Simple:
    def __init__(self, str):
        print("Inside the Simple constructor")
        self.s = str
    # Two methods:
    def show(self):
        print(self.s)
    def showMsg(self, msg):
        print(msg + ':',
        self.show())
```

I'm playing around with it in the python shell and did the following:

```
x = Simple("A constructor argument")
x.show()
```

which outputs:

```
A constructor argument
```

This makes sense to me, however I then input:

```
x.showMsg("A message")
```

Which outputs:

```
A constructor argument
A Message:None
```

This is where I'm confused. Why is the call to the self.show() in showMsg() resulting in "None" when x.Show() results in "A constructor argument"? I thought that self was a placeholder until an instance of the class was created, which would mean that self.show() in this case would be equivalent to x.show()?

Any help on this would be very appreciated.

Comment: self.show() returns None

Comment: You never `return` anything from `self.show` so it returns `None` implicitly...

Answer (score 0):

Get in the habit of having your functions `return` values. Functions with no `return` statement return `None` by default.

Here is an example of how you might rewrite your program:

```
class Simple:
    def __init__(self, str):
        self.s = str
    # Two methods:
    def show(self):
        return self.s
    def showMsg(self, msg):
        return msg + ': ' + self.show()

x = Simple("A constructor argument")

print(x.show())
# A constructor argument

print(x.showMsg('A message'))
# A message: A constructor argument
```

While you can have `print` inside your class, it's a better idea to have your class handle logic and have flexibility with what you do with the results (print them, store them in a list, pass them on to another function, etc).

Answer (score 0):

What the `show()` method in your class does is just print the stored message, however, what `showMsg` is trying to do concatenating some `msg` with the stored one, by calling the `show` method, however, since show() returns nothing, or None, it will get cat'ed just like that, you will have to change your method to either:

```
def show(self):
    return self.s
```

or

```
def show(self):
    print(self.s)
    return self.s
```

In the second case you will retain the functionality for both cases, but it is bad practice